# Creating recursive connection threads

Tags: python, listener, multiprocessing

I create a new connection thread each time a connection with a client is made. However on the second time I run a client script, I get an error, how come?

**The Client**

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
conn = Client(('localhost', 5555), authkey='secret_password')
conn.send('Hello World!')
conn.close()
```

**The Server**

```
import time
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
from threading import Thread

_threads = []
_listener = Listener(('localhost', 5555), authkey='secret_password')

def start_server_thread():
    global _threads
    _threads.append(Thread(target=threaded_server))
    _threads[-1].daemon = True
    _threads[-1].start()

def threaded_server():
    conn = _listener.accept()
    print str(conn.recv())
    conn.close()
    _listener.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server_thread()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

**The Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\spyker\t2.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = Client(('localhost', 5555), authkey='secret_password')
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 143, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 263, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems with this server code.

You are closing the listener after the first connection

You arent looping for more connections

```
import time
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
from threading import Thread

_threads = []

def start_server_thread():
    global _threads
    _threads.append(Thread(target=threaded_server))
    _threads[-1].daemon = True
    _threads[-1].start()

def threaded_server():
    while True:
        conn = _listener.accept()
        print str(conn.recv())
        conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _listener = Listener(('localhost', 5555), authkey='secret_password')

    start_server_thread()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

    _listener.close()
```

Disclaimer: I think is is kind of a messy way to write the server. I am only posting a fix for your current code :-)

Here is a slightly cleaned up version of your same code. Still not 100% ideal but cleaner I think?

```
import time
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
from threading import Thread

class Server(Listener):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Server, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._thread = None
        self._stopping = False


    def serve(self):
        self._stopping = False
        self._thread = Thread(target=self._serve)
        self._thread.daemon = True
        self._thread.start()

    def _serve(self):
        threads = []
        while not self._stopping:
            conn = self.accept()
            t = Thread(target=self.handleConnection, args=(conn,))
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)


    def stop(self):
        if not self._stopping:
            print "Stopping."
            self._stopping = True
            self._thread.join(3)
            self.close()  

    def handleConnection(self, conn):
        print str(conn.recv())
        conn.close()        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener = Server(('localhost', 5555), authkey='secret_password')
    listener.serve()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
        listener.stop()
```

Comment: you're right. my main problem was that I closed the listener and didn't loop over accepting a new connection

Comment: @Jonathan - Just updated the second example to show you how to hand the connection off to a threaded handler so the server loop doesnt block

Answer (score 2):

Some errors spotted:

- You probably want your threaded_server to have an infinite loop and accept more than one connection. Right now it accepts only the first one and exists.
- You're closing the listener after the processing is over, which probably isn't what you want. You can accept more connections using the same listener.

Correct threaded_server():

```
def threaded_server():
    while True:
        conn = _listener.accept()
        print str(conn.recv())
        conn.close()
```

Comment: you're right. my main problem was that I closed the listener and didn't loop over accepting a new connection

Answer (score 0):

The corrected code, using advice from other answers. Corrected lines are marked:

```
import time
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
from threading import Thread

_threads = []
_listener = Listener(('localhost', 5555), authkey='secret_password')

def start_server_thread():
    global _threads
    _threads.append(Thread(target=threaded_server))
    _threads[-1].daemon = True
    _threads[-1].start()

def threaded_server():
    conn = _listener.accept()
    start_server_thread()         # <== each connection creates the next one
    print str(conn.recv())
    conn.close()
                                  # <== removed _listener.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server_thread()
    try:                          # <==
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:  # <== catch ^c
        _listener.close()         # <==
```

Comment: this is wrong. why are you having each thread create a new thread recursively? The examples you were shown before were correct, using a while loop to process each connection. If you want each connection to have an event loop then you should only have a single server loop that accepts the connection and spawns a thread. not calling the server recursively

Comment: I have just updated my second example in my answer to show you how to hand each connection off to a handler in a thread

Comment: @jdi - A connection could stay up for a very long while, in parallel to new connections. I only reduced the connection to a single receive for simplicity. Therefore a while loop would not help, I need a separate thread per connection so they won't block each other.

Comment: The while loop in my second example works just for that purpose. It only blocks waiting for a new connection. Once the connection is received, it is dispatched to a handler in a new thread, and then the server immediately goes and waits for a new connection. The difference is that you are starting a new thread of the SERVER every time to listen for a connection. My example has a single server listener loop, and threads are only created when an actual connection is received. I believe its A LOT simpler to only have your server loop running in a single thread for control.